# How to update only matching subset of object properties in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have two types that share some properties:

```
type A = {
  shared1: string;
  shared2: string;
  notShared1: string;
};

type B = { 
  shared1: string;
  shared2: string;
  notShared2: string;
};
```

Now, I just want to update the matching subset of properties for two of these objects:

```
class MyClass {
  private const a = {
    shared1: "s1",
    shared2: "s2",
    notShared1: "ns1"
  };

  // how can I achieve something like this:
  private const b = { ...a, notShared2: "ns2" } // but without the 'notShared1' property of a
}
```

### My idea

I tried to `.filter` the first object by the matching keys but unfortunately the method itself doens't work:

```
private updateB() {
  this.b = { ...this.a.filter(Object.keys(b)) } // filter method not available, why? 
  // (the filter content is not correct, just for better understanding what I try to achieve here)
}
```

Comment: `this.a` is an *object*, not an array. And if it was an array it's unclear what you're trying to achieve by passing `b.keys()` where a *callback* is expected.

Comment: It's not possible because this would be a runtime feature, and types are not available during runtime.

Comment: array of keys can be obtained via `Object.keys(a)`

Comment: The filter method is not available because you can only [`filter Arrays{}`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) but not [`Objects{}`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object). There are many ways to achieve what you want, but I'd start by trying to improve your data structure first, and understand how to interact with different data types in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

This is something you can do in JavaScript. Given your definitions of a and b, runtime objects can be updated like:

```
a = { shared1: "s1", shared2: "s2", notShared1: "ns1" };
b = { shared1: "not s1", shared2: "not s2", notShared2: "ns2" };

for (const key in a) {
  if (b.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    b[key] = a[key];
  }
}
console.log(b);
// output: Object { shared1: "s1", shared2: "s2", notShared2: "" }
```